# GTrends Location Mistmatch to US Census Shapefiles

Tags: r, shapefile, geo, census, gtrendsr

I am trying to link data from Google Trends with geocode data from Census. This is an example of the location data provided by Google Trends for Florida:

```
 sub_code                           name
US-FL-571                    Ft. Myers-Naples, FL
US-FL-592                         Gainesville, FL
US-FL-561                        Jacksonville, FL
US-FL-528                Miami-Ft. Lauderdale, FL
US-FL-534     Orlando-Daytona Beach-Melbourne, FL
US-FL-656                         Panama City, FL
```

More details about this output can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318748/gtrendsr-geo-msa-area-code?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) .

From [here](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_msa.html), one can download the MSA shapefiles. I have downloaded the 2017 CBSAs data at 20m resolution. Here is the corresponding data for Florida:

```
 [1] "Wauchula, FL"                             
 [2] "Deltona-Daytona Beach-Ormond Beach, FL"   
 [3] "Port St. Lucie, FL"                       
 [4] "Arcadia, FL"                              
 [5] "Punta Gorda, FL"                          
 [6] "Sebring, FL"                              
 [7] "Homosassa Springs, FL"                    
 [8] "Key West, FL"                             
 [9] "Sebastian-Vero Beach, FL"                 
[10] "Tampa-St. Petersburg-Clearwater, FL"      
[11] "Crestview-Fort Walton Beach-Destin, FL"   
[12] "Okeechobee, FL"                           
[13] "Jacksonville, FL"                         
[14] "Tallahassee, FL"                          
[15] "Orlando-Kissimmee-Sanford, FL"            
[16] "Miami-Fort Lauderdale-West Palm Beach, FL"
[17] "Gainesville, FL"                          
[18] "The Villages, FL"                         
[19] "Palatka, FL"                              
[20] "Lakeland-Winter Haven, FL"                
[21] "Lake City, FL"                            
[22] "Ocala, FL"                                
[23] "North Port-Sarasota-Bradenton, FL"        
[24] "Pensacola-Ferry Pass-Brent, FL"           
[25] "Cape Coral-Fort Myers, FL"                
[26] "Naples-Immokalee-Marco Island, FL"        
[27] "Palm Bay-Melbourne-Titusville, FL"        
[28] "Clewiston, FL"                            
[29] "Panama City, FL"
```

I understand Gtrends has a subset of all possible MSAs, but while some match perfectly (e.g. Panama City, FL), for others it is not very clear what should be merged with what. For example, Ft.Myers-Naples, FL from the first data could be merged with Cape Coral-Fort Myers, FL or with Naples-Immokalee-Marco Island, FL.

I would appreciate any guidance in dealing with such inconsistencies. Perhaps I am missing something obvious, so if you spot it, it'd be great to know!